# When should I use errors-in-variables?

Tags: regression, bias, errors-in-variables

I have been reading about errors-in-variables (also called regression dilution and attenuation) but I've found it hard to decide whether it is appropriate for my setting.

I want to calculate correlations, and I've read that due to measurement errors, the computed correlations will be underestimated.

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_for_attenuation), it says that for two random variables $\beta, \theta$ with estimates

$\hat{\beta} = \beta + \epsilon_\beta, \;\;\; \hat{\theta} = \theta + \epsilon_\theta,$

where $\epsilon_\beta$ and $\epsilon_\theta$ are measurement errors associated with the estimates, the correlation can be expressed as

${\rm corr}(\hat{\beta},\hat{\theta}) = \rho \sqrt{R_\beta R_\theta},$

where $R_\beta$ is calculated by

$R_\beta = \displaystyle \frac{{\rm var}(\beta)}{{\rm var}(\beta) + {\rm var}(\epsilon_\beta)} =\displaystyle \frac{{\rm var}(\hat{\beta}) - {\rm var}(\epsilon_\beta)}{{\rm var}(\hat{\beta})},$

and $R_\theta$ is calculated equivalently. Thus the disattenuated $\rho$ is found by

$\rho = \displaystyle \frac{{\rm corr}(\hat{\beta},\hat{\theta})}{\sqrt{R_\beta R_\theta}}.$

My setting is that I am doing several measurements of three quantities (distance to, angle from reference line, height) at different locations.

Can I use this formula for calculating correlations, substituting the manufacturer's given uncertainty in measurements as ${\rm var}(\epsilon_\beta)$?

Edit:
The measurements are done in land surveying. The measured quantities are distance, angle and height, $d, \theta, z$, measured from a measuring station, which location is considered known, to a number of reflector stations with unknown location. That is, the measuring station has a reference location, and the distance to the reflector stations, as well as height at the stations, and angle difference from some reference angle.

The three quantities are measured by laser. Several measurements are made according to given procedures.

I read in [this report](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf) that measurements made with the same instrument may be correlated due to measurement uncertainty. Because of this I suspect that height, distance and angle measured from the measuring station to one given reflector station might be correlated. Also, I suspect that the measurement procedure can give rise to correlations between the angles measured at different stations (locations). If this interpretation is wrong, please let me know!

The data is to be presented and further analysed in a Cartesian coordinate system, $(x, y, z')$, (while the measurements are in a spherical coordinate system) so to find the standard deviation in, say, $x  = d \sin(\theta)$ I need to calculate covariances.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to calculate correlations? That, after all, is not usually anybody's real objective: it's just a procedure for characterizing data.  What are you really trying to learn about length, angle, and height?

Comment: Thank you for the question, @whuber! I've edited my question, hopefully it is more clear now. Please shout out if you think I am on the wrong track calculating correlations.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write $z=d\sin(\theta)$ (instead of $x$). Do you have any reason to believe the measurements of $d$ and $\theta$ may be correlated? If not, you can work out the distribution of $d\sin(\theta)$ from the distributions of $d$ and $\theta$.

Comment: No, I meant $x$, I mean that the data will be transformed to a different coordinate system than the one they are measured in, so to say. The reason I believe they are correlated stem from measurement technicalities and the fact that the three quantities are measured at the same time. I read in a JCGM report that it could cause correlations

Comment: I'm totally confused now, and possibly others are as well.  Could you clarify the relationships among $x$, $d$, $\theta$, and $z$ and indicate which are data, how they are measured, and what exactly you need to estimate with them?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so unclear! I am new to land surveying. I have edited it now, I hope it is understandable. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: It is of interest that all three measurements are made simultaneously by a single instrument. But how, exactly, does a laser obtain a *height* difference? Isn't it really measuring a distance and the elevation angle and merely performing the multiplication height = distance * sin(angle)? How does it measure the angle--are you reading that off some kind of inclinometer?

Comment: The height $z$ is measured as an angle from zenith (the line straight up in the air). That is, the measurement is an angle, and in a cartesian coordinate system, $(x', y', z')$, $z' = d \cos(z)$. The angles are measured as rotation from zenith and from a set reference direction.

Comment: +1 for referencing the GUM (Guide to uncertainty in measurement) ! Also you didn't give the relative accuracy of your laser survey instrument, compared with the accuracy you are hoping to obtain. If the laser has a random uncertainty (type A) of 20cm (k=2), and you want 15cm accuracy, and you also have some bias/systematic uncertainty (i.e. guessed) then you have to take many measurements, etc.

Comment: @Gunnhild, your measurements are unlikely to be correlated, but likely to have the same bias. The bias may be correlated with the surveyor,

Answer (score 1):

Describing the nature and extent of measurement error is a very good practice for statisticians. The next important implication for practice is to interpret the results and findings in a contextually appropriate manner, which may confuse the reader somewhat, but doesn't convey false associations. For instance, suppose we observe in-patient admits to a mental hospital and measure pain sensitivity and successful rehabilitation from addictive substances. In survey items about the frequency and intensity of pain, we are careful to refer to associations as describing *self reported* pain. If such patients are being considered as eligible for benzos or opiods, we might expect *exaggeration* of the pain response among those less likely to response to rehab therapies.

In epidemiology, the above example could be referred to as differential misclassification. Even non-differential misclassification has implications on the measured associations. In particular, *attentuation* is a problem. However, in most circumstances, associations can be measured in the presence of attenuation. Hence we are capable of making inference on associations, but predicted values in non-linear trends are biased, and confidence intervals for effects may be too large. For inference, attenuation is less of a problem than it seems.

If we had an estimate of the measurement error, then it's possible to extend maximum likelihood methods to obtain unbiased estimates of associations. In particular, this would involve the use of the EM Algorithm. It turns out this is equivalent to a latent variable approach where a latent variable is added between your measurement-errored variable and y.